# JSON from Postgres to HTML web form

Tags: html, json, forms

**How would I convert this JSON to a readable HTML that creates list boxes and check boxes? I am trying to using dform for the conversion**

```
 [
                        {
                            "attribute": {
                            "propertyattributecode": "ConstructionDecade",
                            "description": "Based on MPF survey construction decade",
                            "type": "list"
                        },
                            "values": [
                        {
                            "propertyattributecode": "ConstructionDecade",
                            "value": "1960"
                        },
                        {
                            "propertyattributecode": "ConstructionDecade",
                            "value": "1970"
                        },
                        {
                            "propertyattributecode": "ConstructionDecade",
                            "value": "1980"
                        },
                        {
                            "propertyattributecode": "ConstructionDecade",
                            "value": "1990"
                        },
                        {
                            "propertyattributecode": "ConstructionDecade",
                            "value": "2000"
                        },
                        {
                            "propertyattributecode": "ConstructionDecade",
                            "value": "2010"
                        }
                    ]
```